# Split arrays and combine into separate arrays based on indexOf position in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, split, indexof

How would I iterate through multiple arrays, ie;

```
array1 = [ "1", "2", "3" ];
array2 = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
array3 = [ "apples", "bananas", "cheese" ];
```

To join back into a series of arrays based on index position like this:

```
result1 = [ "1", "a", "apples" ];
result2 = [ "2", "b", "bananas" ];
result3 = [ "3", "c", "cheese" ];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Map them together to a temp array, and then assign them to original variables ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wyecx7g/)):

```
var array1 = [ "1", "2", "3" ];
var array2 = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
var array3 = [ "apples", "bananas", "cheese" ];

var temp = array1.map(function(value1, index) {
return [value1, array2[index], array3[index]];
});

array1 = temp[0];
array2 = temp[1];
array3 = temp[2];
```

Comment: @Jugnu - Don't micro optimize. Write whatever is more readable to you. If you see a significant performance hit - measure, and then optimize. Most of the time, it will be some stupid logic error, and not .map vs. for.

Comment: I agree with you but you don't think so by practicing more optimized code we can give better solutions after all coding is an art.

Comment: @Jugnu - Optimization is important, but you can't overdo it, and not on the expanse of readability - and this is more readable to me :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution for any length, add another array, like `array4`, or use different length of arrays:

```js
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"],
    array2 = ["a", "b", "c"],
    array3 = ["apples", "bananas", "cheese"],
    result = [array1, array2, array3].reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j) {
            !(j in r) && r.push([]);
            r[j].push(b);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```